# Datagrab import entries - delete entries that do not match

Tags: members, ee, datagrab

I have a client site where they have a large list of members. Each month, the list of active members changes based on offline transactions.

Initially, I used Datagrab to add these members, but as each month arrives, the client wants to delete all members that are not in their CSV file of active members.

Clearly, this isn't EE or Datagrab standard practice, but I was hoping someone could shed some light on a way to tackle this that wouldn't require dumping the entire list and importing from scratch. While a complete purge would be the easy solution, the members that need to stay already have had their passwords set manually and would require even more manual client work.

TIA for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall a similar issue a long time ago. The system was automated so we generated a Cron job to set all entries to 'closed' prior to import. Then when the import ran we set the status to 'open'.

Entries that didn't exist then remained closed.

If your doing it manually, you could run a MySQL query manually then run your import thereafter.